# Распределение загруженных товаров в разные блоки div, в зависимости от значения его параметра

Tags: javascript, json, объекты, интернет-магазин

Доброго времени суток! Создал примитивный интернет-магазин и теперь пытаюсь решить возникшую проблему.

---

**Описание:**
Есть страница-каталог. На ней есть несколько блоков ***div***, в которые я хочу выгружать товары. Но! Каждый такой блок предназначен для отдельной категории товара, например:

Я беру и "выгружаю" товары из **JSON файла**. Дальше я "вытаскиваю" из него параметры товара (название, стоимость, размер и т. д.) и "раскидываю" эти данные на свои места. В конце я вывожу всю эту информацию в тот самый блок ***div***.

**Проблема такая:**

У меня есть разные товары, с разными категориями. Допустим это "фрукты", "овощи" и т. д. В конце все товары попадают в один блок. А я хочу, чтобы "фрукты" попадали в блок "фрукты", "овощи", соответственно, в "овощи" и т. д.

Я попытался осуществить проверку категории, её можно увидеть в моем коде. Естественно, это не работает.

**Пример кода:**

```
function loadGoods() {
//Загружаю товары на страницу:
$.getJSON('goods.json', function(data) {
    var out = '';
    for (var key in data) {
        out += '<div class="market_container">';

        out += '<img src=" ' + data[key].img + ' ">';
        out += '<p class="name">' + data[key] ['name'] + '</p>';
        out += '<p class="size">' + data[key] ['size'] + " г." + '</p>';
        out += '<p class="size">' + data[key] ['categ'] + '</p>';
        out += '<p class="cost"><mark>' + data[key] ['cost'] + " грн" + '</mark></p>' + '<hr>';
        out += '<p class="btn">';

        out += '<a class="add_to_cart" data-art="'+key+'">';
        out += '<i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>' + " В корзину";
        out += '</a>';

        out += '</p>';
        out += '</div>';

        //Проверка категории товара (categ - категория):
        if (data[key] ['categ'] = 'fruit') {
            $('#market_part_category_01').html(out);//Если категория - "фрукты", то выгружаем в этот блок.
        }
        else if (data[key] ['categ'] = 'vegetables') {
            $('#market_part_category_02').html(out);//Если категория - "овощи", то выгружаем в этот блок.
        }
    }
    //Кнопка добавления в корзину:
    $('a.add_to_cart').on('click', addToCart);
});
```

}

Comment: if (data[key] ['categ'] === 'fruit') ? может лучше не "переназначать", а сравнивать?

Comment: Да, действительно, я переназначил, вместо того, чтобы просто сравнить. Однако проблемы все равно есть:
Теперь в первой категории появляются товары из категории "fruit", где и должны быть, а во второй, соответственно, товары из категории "vegetables".
Но во второй категории, кроме "vegetables", снова появляются товары из категории "fruit".

Comment: @Роман попробуй очищать строку out где-то на последней строчке внутри цикла или перенеси var out = ''; внутрь цикла в начало

Comment: @MishaSaidov Да, это и правда помогло. Теперь каждый товар отображается в своей категории.

Но вот незадача: Вместо отображения всех товаров, отображается лишь один в каждой категории. Примечательно то, что это последний товар из каждой категории.

Comment: @Роман не .html(out), а .append(out)

Comment: @MishaSaidov Большое Вам спасибо. Это правда помогло. Все работает как надо!

Спасибо!